# C# Binding to Gridview column displaying class name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, binding

I'm trying bind data to gridview columns within a listview, however it only outputs the name of the class (namespace.pkscheme) instead of the actual data.

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,20,10,10" Name="pkcsTable">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Author" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding author}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Screenshot" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding screenshot}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Download" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding download}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C#: I have have a list of the class 'pkscheme' called 'pkschemes'

```
public class pkscheme
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string author { get; set; }
public string screenshot { get; set; }
public string download { get; set; }
}

pkcs_w = new UserControl1();
pkcs_w.Width = 800;
pkcs_w.Height = 500;
pkcs_w.pkcsTable.ItemsSource = pkschemes;
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed the tutorial here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

EDIT: I've got it working with a listbox, which uses a data template, perhaps listview needs one aswell?

Comment: Show pkschemes definition.

Comment: pkschemes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<pkscheme>>(sj); But it doesn't really matter because the list is working fine, it outputs all the correct data when tested. Its just the binding which isn't working

Comment: You don't need ItemsSource="{Binding }" since you set it directly in code-behind as latter code depicts.

Comment: doesn't make a difference

Comment: It shows name of class "pkscheme" ?

Comment: yes namespace.pkscheme

Comment: Any binding error in Output window?

Comment: nope, everything runs fine.

Comment: Add following object <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pkcsTable, Path=ItemsSorce.Count}"/> it will show how many items contains ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code. It is working for me. This is how the code which I tried looks:

**UserControl1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="minimizeApp.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,20,10,10" Name="pkcsTable">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Author" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding author}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Screenshot" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding screenshot}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Download" Width="195" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding download}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="minimizeApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="grid1">

</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
 namespace minimizeApp
    {

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<pkscheme> pkschemes = new List<pkscheme>();

        UserControl1 pkcs_w = null;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //1st row
            pkscheme pk = new pkscheme();
            pk.name = "pk";
            pk.author = "pkAuthor";
            pk.screenshot = "pkScreenshot";
            pk.download = "pkDownload";

            //2nd row
            pkscheme pk1 = new pkscheme();
            pk1.name = "pk1";
            pk1.author = "pkAuthor1";
            pk1.screenshot = "pkScreenshot1";
            pk1.download = "pkDownload1";

            pkschemes.Add(pk);
            pkschemes.Add(pk1);

            pkcs_w = new UserControl1();
            pkcs_w.Width = 800;
            pkcs_w.Height = 500;
            pkcs_w.pkcsTable.ItemsSource = pkschemes;

            grid1.Children.Add(pkcs_w);
        }
    }

    public class pkscheme
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public string screenshot { get; set; }
        public string download { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ItemsSource="{Binding}"

Comment: Doesn't do anything, I've gone between having and not having it multiple times :/